# Adding multiple forms for a single java Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, crud

I was trying to learn about **java servlet** and **JSP**. At some time I hit this problem. I have this **ADMIN.jsp**, where I wrote all the **HTML** forms for CRUD operations. The thing I don't know is how to call whatever form I what from my **AdminServelt**, for instance if I click the **Delete** button on web interface, I want my servlet to know what form to choose from JSP and delete whatever I decide throw the form's input.

Comment: You cannot control from Servlet which HTML form should be picked. Instead, you can control from HTML Form which Servlet should be submitted. It would be wise to define different Servlet for each CRUD Operation and pass their respective path on each form action attribute.

Comment: So what you're saying is to make DeleteServlet, UpdateServlet, Post and GetServlet? I do appreciete your answer, but it has to be something quicker. I mean it is possible for a form to pass something to the servlet, a value? Because in that case a simple switch in the Servlet will solve everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to enter one hidden parameter like

`<input type="hidden" name="purpose" value="C/R/U/D">`

in the jsp file.

On servlet you will pass value of parameter into new variable

```
    String decisionParam = request.getParameter("purpose");

if(decisionParam.equals("C"){ 

//process create logic
}
else if(decisionParam.equals("R")) {
//process read logic
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Write a form like this in JSP:

```
<form method="post" action="/AdminServlet?edit"> </form>
```

This one is for Edit, for example. And you can try something like this in AdminServlet, if you want to check if you clicked on Edit button:

```
 if (request.getQueryString().equals("edit")) {}
```